# Getting an error message when compiling typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following piece of code:

```
class BasketManager {
    private persistPromises: { [key: string]: ng.IPromise<Basket.BasketModel> } = {};

    constructor(private $q: ng.IQService) {}

    order(basket: Basket.BasketModel, simulate = false): ng.IPromise<Basket.BasketModel> {
        return this.persistPromises[basket.basketId] = this.$q.when(this.persistPromises[basket.basketId] || basket).then(basket => {
            return this.$http.post(url, {})
                .then((response:ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<API.Contracts.IBasketContract>) => this.storeBasket(response.data, true))
                .catch((response:ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<any>) => this.handleBasketErrorResponse(basket, response));
        });
    });

    private storeBasket(data: API.Contracts.IBaseBasketContract, withItems = false): Basket.BasketModel {
        /* ... */
    }

    private handleBasketErrorResponse(basket: Basket.BasketModel, response: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<any>): Basket.BasketModel {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

When I try to compile it, I get this error message:

```
TypeScript error: app/scripts/objectmanager/basketmanager.service.ts(100,60): error TS2453: The type argument for type parameter 'TResult' cannot be inferred from the usage. Consider specifying the type arguments explicitly.
  Type argument candidate 'IBaseBasketContract' is not a valid type argument because it is not a supertype of candidate 'BasketModel'.
```

100,60 is 7,56 in the above snippet.

I tried explicitly specifying the arguments for each and every variable, but that didn't help. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like I found the answer myself. Replaced the line with the error with this:

```
return this.persistPromises[basket.basketId] = this.$q.when(this.persistPromises[basket.basketId] || basket).then<Basket.BasketModel>(basket => {
```